# como adicionar imagens em um ListViewGroup

Tags: vb.net, listview

Vamos supor que nesse caminho: `C:\...\imagem` tenham 3 pastas: `fotos`, `wallpaper` e `ferias`. O que eu gostaria de fazer e deixa-las assim:

**Fotos**

```
imagem1           imagem2              imagem3

imagem4           imagem5              imagem6
```

**Wallpaper**

```
imagem1           imagem2              imagem3

imagem4           imagem5              imagem6
```

**Ferias**

```
imagem1           imagem2              imagem3

imagem4           imagem5              imagem6
```

Eu já peguei os caminhos e as imagens, mas to apanhando para esse listview alguém sabe como faço isso?

Se possível usando linguagem propiá do vb não sei C#

Edit:

Eu estou usando um Treeview para listar todas as pastar de um diretório que tenham imagens .jpg

```
 Dim td As Threading.Thread


Private Sub Anteslerdiretorio()
    Dim nome As String = "Imagem"
    Dim caminho As String = "C:\Users\lucas\Imagem\fotos"

    Dim cont As Integer = 0


    'Dim node As TreeNode = New TreeNode(nome)
    Me.Invoke(New Action(Function() Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nome)))

    LerDiretoriosEArquivosRecursivamenteEAdicionarAaTreeView(caminho, TreeView1.Nodes(cont))
    cont += 1



End Sub

Private Sub LerDiretoriosEArquivosRecursivamenteEAdicionarAaTreeView(ByVal diretorio As String, ByVal noPai As TreeNode)

    Dim dirsFilhos() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(diretorio)
    If dirsFilhos.Length = 0 Then
        Return
    Else
        For Each dirFilho In dirsFilhos
            Try
                For Each arquivos In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(dirFilho, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.jpg", "*.png")
                    If Len(arquivos) > 0 Then
                        Dim noFilho As TreeNode = New TreeNode(dirFilho)
                        Me.Invoke(New Action(Function() noPai.Nodes.Add(noFilho)))
                        'noPai.Nodes.Add(noFilho)
                        LerDiretoriosEArquivosRecursivamenteEAdicionarAaTreeView(dirFilho, noFilho)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            Finally
            End Try
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    td = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Anteslerdiretorio)

    td.Start()

End Sub
```

E depois usando um evento AfterSelect do treeview para pegar o caminho selecionado no Treeview e as imagens na pasta selecionada.

```
Private Sub PegaCaminhoTreeview(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

    If TreeView1.SelectedNode Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Dim thumbnail As New ImageList With {.ImageSize = New Size(256, 200), .ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit}
    Dim caminho_saida As String = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text
    Dim xx As Image

    Try
        For Each caminho_imagens In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*jpg", "*.png")
            Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(caminho_imagens)
                xx = Image.FromStream(str)
                thumbnail.Images.Add(xx)
            End Using
        Next
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é como eu faço uma exibição desse tipo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que com o nome da última pasta sendo o nome do grupo e suas respectivas imagens dentro do grupo da pasta.

Comment: Olá @Lucas, tem algum código já feito?

Comment: @Lucas qual é a duvida em concreto? Código por favor.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Qual a sua dificuldade ao certo?

Comment: Criar o grupo no Listview com o nome da pasta e colocar as imagens dela dentro do grupo igual na imagem acima.